# Закрыть сокет в Java

Tags: java, eclipse, сокет, сокеты

Здравствуйте!

Как в Java закрыть сокет при нажатии на кнопку?
Сделал приложения клиент, сервер. Нужно при нажатии на кнопку на сервере отключать определенного клиента. Пробовал использовать флаг. Проблема в том, что в потоках приложение ждет текста от клиента, и после того, как она принимает текст начинает проверять флаг и отключает сокет... А мне нужно чтобы какое-то прерывание чтоль это делало..

До сих пор вожусь, не получается. Может сегодня найдется тот кто знает как это делается...
Спасибо.

Comment: Я пока ещё не успел поработать с сокетами в Java, и может чего-то не понимаю, но разве Thread.stop() не остановить поток?

Comment: Мне не нужно останавливать поток, мне нужно прервать работу метода String input = in.readLine();  в потоке, а потом решать закрыть сокет или нет...

Answer (score 2):

Класс Socket реализует интерфейс Closable.
Почему вызов метода close() не подходит?)

Answer (score 1):

Уменьши время ожидания, вызвав метод `setSoTimeout();`
как только получил сокет, сразу вызывай его

Comment: Мне нужно как-то прерывать вот это String input = in.readLine(); Приложение ждет строку тут... Нужно как-то его пересбрасывать чтоли...